# Do threads work with respect to their respective priority number?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-priority

Why would the compiler print `2 a` and then `2 b` or vice versa when giving the priority to `Thread` a to start? Shouldn't thread `b` wait for thread `a` to finish in order to start? Can someone please explain how does it work?

```
public class Test1 extends Thread{
    static int x = 0;
    String name;

    Test1(String n) {
      name = n;
    }

    public void increment() {
        x = x+1;
        System.out.println(x + " " + name);
    }

    public void run() {
        this.increment();
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test1 a = new Test1("a");
        Test1 b = new Test1("b");
        a.setPriority(3);
        b.setPriority(2);
        a.start();
        b.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving priorities is not a job for the compiler.  It is the OS scheduler to schedule and give CPU time (called quantum) to threads.

The scheduler further tries to run as much threads at once as possible, based on the available number of CPUs.  In today's multicore systems, more often than not more than one core are available.

If you want for a thread to wait for another one, use some synchronizing mechanism.

Comment: What's the importance of priorities then?

Comment: @HusseinJaber Threads with a higher priority are given preference by the CPU scheduler; so in a contended situation, threads with a higher priority will generally be run instead of those with a lower priority.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, That's _usually_ true. Fact is though, Thread priorities mean nothing in Java. It's just a number--a hint--that gets passed on to the operating system.  Most desktop, mobile-device, and server operating systems treat priority as a _weight_: When two threads both want 100% of available CPU, they'll allow a low priority thread to preempt a higher priority thread, but on average, they'll give a larger share of CPU to the thread with higher priority.  A real-time OS, on the other hand, might never allow a low priority thread to preempt one with higher priority.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, you're right, I didn't want to go into too much detail in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

> Shouldn't thread b wait for thread a to finish in order to start?

No. The priority does not *block* the thread execution. It only tells the JVM to *execute* the thread ["in preference to threads with lower priority"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). This does imply a wait.

Since your code is so trivial, there is nothing to wait for. Any of the two threads is run.

Answer (score 1):

> Why would the compiler print 2 a and then 2 b?

Luck of the draw. "Priority" means different things on different operating systems, but in general, it's always part of how the OS decides which thread gets to run and which one must wait when there's not enough CPUs available to run them both at the same time. If you computer has two or more idle CPUs when you start that program, then everybody gets to run. Priority doesn't matter in that case, and its just a race to see which one gets to the `println(...)` call first.

The `a` thread in your example has an advantage because the program doesn't call `b.start()` until after the `a.start()` method returns, but how big that advantage actually is depends on the details of the OS thread scheduling algorithm.  The `a` thread could get a huge head start (like, it actually finishes before `b` even starts), or it could be a near-trivial head start.